# Make Preview auto append file extension in macOS 10.15 Catalina

Tags: preview

I have set the file extension to be shown in Finder settings.

When I open a JPEG in Preview, and try to File > Export and re-save it as JPEG for lower/higher quality, the file name's file extension is gone. I have to manually add `.jpg` in the file name when I save the file.

How to prevent Preview remove the file extension?

PS: It seems to be fixed in 10.16 Big Sur

Comment: It's not that it doesn't add it, it's that it hides it by default. You can toggle that per file in Get Info, but idk how to make it not hide initially.

Comment: @Tetsujin you are right. After saving the file, the "Hide extension" checkbox is checked in the "Get Info" dialog, which doesn't make sense. This per-file setting is weird.

Comment: Some apps have a checkbox in the save dialog, 'hide extension'… which just isn't there on preview.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I cannot replicate this behaviour in Big Sur. **File > Export** in Preview has a file extension, and that changes when I alter the format type.

In fact, even if I remove the file extension in the dialog, the file still gets a `.jpg` file extension.

However, a quick test of unchecking the Finder option to show extensions shows that it doesn't work: even after restarting Finder and opening new windows, the option doesn't change. So that might be a bug.

You could try the command line option instead:

```
defaults write NSGlobalDomain AppleShowAllExtensions -bool true
```

and then Force Quit the Finder, or restart.

If the option is still set to hide, then you won't see the extension in file dialogs. (In effect, you're name files `myfile.jpg.jpg`, but the last extension is hidden, and the first one is indeed 'useless'.)

Comment: I am using macOS 10.15 Catalina. If I don't add the `.jpg` in Preview save dialog, the Finder doesn't show the file extension, even when I relaunch the Finder via the Force Quit menu. I checked the filename with `ls -al` in Terminal and found that the file extension is there; it's just the display of Finder has problems. Glad to know it's fixed in Big Sur.